# Is this the proper way to use assert in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, assert

Is this the proper way to use assert?

My program takes some files names as command line arguments and stores them in a list. I need to cross reference the list of file names with names in a metadata file. If one of the files isn't in the metadata, I want the program to end and explain why. I thought assert might be good for that but I'm not sure if this is the proper way to use it or if there is a better way to iterate over a list and make sure it exists in the metadata.

```
for sample in samples_list:
    assert(sample in meta_sampleIds), "A file is missing from the metadata"
```

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary and misleading.

Comment: Note that assertions are removed when running with `-O`. You probably don't want that if you are checking a file for consistency (which is outside of your control)...

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Oh, that's true. I do not want that.